# How to use HTTPS in Azure Web API

Tags: azure, https, asp.net-web-api

Currently my application url coresponds to HTTP only. How can I make it compatible with HTTPS also.. Can I do that specifically to single service only.

Comment: Hello, Anish. Do you intend to solve your problem with code? If so, I hope you get the answer you're after. If not, then I suggest you check one of Stack Overflow's sister sites: [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com). For server administration and configuration questions, you will get better answers there. Just sign in with the same account you use here.

Comment: I have replicated the question as per ur suggestion.. By code also am struggling..

Answer (score 1):

For first you should upload your SSL certificate through Azure Management panel (.pfx with private key) and attach it to your cloud service or web site.

Then setup HTTPS endpoint for your WEB API web role within your Azure cloud project, there you should also define SSL certificate thumbprint.

Regards.